# bokeh server- rejected connection because host is not in whitelist

Tags: windows, server, bokeh

I am trying to run a simple bokeh server script on my local machine:

```
#app.py
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from random import randrange
#create figure
f=figure(x_range=(0,11),y_range=(0,11))

#create columndatasource
source=ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=[],y=[]))

#create glyphs
f.circle(x='x',y='y',size=8,fill_color='olive',line_color='yellow',source=source)

#create periodic function
def update():
    new_data=dict(x=[randrange(1,10)],y=[randrange(1,10)])
    source.stream(new_data,rollover=15)
    print(source.data)

#add figure to curdoc and configure callback
curdoc().add_root(f)
curdoc().add_periodic_callback(update,1000)`
```

On the command line I tried various combinations of:

`bokeh serve app.py`
`bokeh serve app.py --port 5100`
`bokeh serve app.py --host *`
`bokeh serve app.py --allow-websocket-origin=127.0.0.1:80`

they all return a message saying the host was rejected because it is not on the whitelist. I am running windows. What is going wrong?

Hilariously, I actually got it working before lunch. After rewarding myself with food, it stopped working and I have not been able to get it since. I believe the working combination used `--port` and `--allow-websocket`

Comment: this just in! doing `bokeh serve app.py --address=0.0.0.0 --host=* --allow-websocket-origin=*` yielded a blank page rather than "403 Forbidden". Woohoo. It could also be related to tornado, which I've downgraded to 4.4.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first, if you just run

```
bokeh serve --show app.py
```

Then Bokeh will automatically raise a browser window opened to the correct URL.  The deafult URL would be

```
http://localhost:5006/app
```

Note that's `localhost` and not `127.0.0.1`

A few other notes:

- `--allow-websocket-origin` is only needed if you are embedding a Bokeh app in a different, separate website with its own address. It is not need just to view locally.
- The (confusing) `--host` parameter was deprecated and removed (perhaps you have an old version?) but would also not be needed to view locally
- `--address` tells the Bokeh server which network addresses to listen on, again not typically needed for local.
- `--port` tells the Bokeh server what network port to listen on rather than the default port of 5006. E.g.

  ```
  bokeh serve --port 8080 --show app.py
  ```

  would result in an app accessible here:

  ```
  http://localhost:8080/app
  ```

If this does not help then more information is needed. Specifically, the *exact* error messages, which you have not provided, or some indication of what URL you are actually trying to navigate to (since that is half of the issue).

Comment: semi related followup: updating bokeh broke plots that used to work. Is there some tool (or something) that magically updates bokeh 0.12.1 scripts to be compatible with current versions? Or am I dreaming?

Comment: No there it is not, but we try to publish comprehensive migration guides in the release notes, e.g. https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/releases/0.12.10.html#migration-guide  We are working towards a stable 1.0 release soon but paradoxically this spikes churn a bit in the short term, since in any breaking changes have to get in *before* 1.0 is released (or basically never happen)

Answer (score 0):

the answer is version control. Tornado 4.4.2 worked but 4.5.3 did not

Comment: When tornado 4.5 first came out, it made a breaking change that broke existing releases of the Bokeh server. The next release of Bokeh restored compatibility with Tornado 4.5 so another option is to upgrade your Bokeh version.