# How to host a bokeh framework app in the internet?

Tags: http, bokeh

I created an app with python bokeh (https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/). I can run it on my local system using `bokeh serve --show dir`. How can I host this on the internet to a wider audience?

https://github.com/Lhogeshwaran/bokeh_data_visualization

Comment: You can use a hosting service such as Heroku: https://pjandir.github.io/Bokeh-Heroku-Tutorial/

Comment: Not really related to python. You should post it to ServerFault maybe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55049175/running-bokeh-server-on-local-network/55051181#55051181) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48533745/bokeh-server-rejected-connection-because-host-is-not-in-whitelist). Try to run your app first on a local network like in the first example. Then if you want to make it available to the www then change the run command line as follows: `--address` argument should be the IP address of your webserver and if you want your Bokeh app can be viewed from any IP address then specify `--allow-websocket-origin="*:5001"` (or `--allow-websocket-origin=*`, I am not sure about exact syntax) or provide a specific IP addresses one by one to give access only to few computers. The port number 5001 is just an example. and should be the same as the port Bokeh uses (can be default 5006). Please be aware that doing so and not applying any security measures is a big risk to your computer.